# Change fore color hyperlink using datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink

i have hyperlink that the color of text will diffrent based on it value, if the value is 0, the color is black, if the value >0 it will red, here the code i have tried

```
ForeColor='<%#IIf(Eval("exception") = 0, "Black", "Red")%>'
```

but it give me error"

> "The server tag is not well formed."

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can change its property in code behind.You just have to assign different CssClass based on values in value change event.

```
HyperLink1.CssClass = "NewClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like below,

ForeColor='<%#(DataBinder.Eval("exception").ToString()=="0") ? "Black" : "Red"%>'